# How do I update Blogger account?

Tags: blogger

I was trying to add my google analytics tracking ID to my HTML and everything got really messed up. There was an error, so I undid what I added but it still wouldn't save due to an error. So I exited out of that page and it said "your changes may not be saved" but now there's a warning message across my blog and I can't find anything about how to get it off the page? I've attached a screenshot of what it looks like... the URL is www.mooretori.com if there's a way to see if it looks like this for someone else too?

---

**Picture of the error message**

[image: [1]]

It's a premium blogger theme and I've never had this problem before, and even when I reuploaded the original theme from the template I bought the problem was still there.

I'm terrible at coding so I just don't know what to do next!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you place your code - in HTML gadget or in Blogger theme editor? In second variant, remove all, that you added, and place `<b:include name='google-analytics' data='blog'/>` before `</body>` tag. Then, read [this article](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/7039627?hl=en) in Blogger support.